# Progresshud without rounded corner background view

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

I want to remove background view for mbprogresshud. I am trying set color and background color of bezelView to clear color, but its not showing what i exactly wanted. Is there any way to remove background view from hud. My code is like this

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES];
[hud.bezelView setColor:kColorMainParentColor];
[hud.bezelView setBackgroundColor:kColorMainParentColor];
[hud.bezelView setStyle:MBProgressHUDBackgroundStyleBlur];
[hud setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]];
```

Comment: how do you added the mbprogresshud in pods or manual

Answer (score 0):

Find this line `bezelView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;` from `MBProgressHUD.m` file and delete or comment it out.